# fasterRaster package warnings in R

Tags: r

When I use the fasterRaster package to calculate the following problem, how do I solve it?

```
> grassDir <- 'C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 7.8'
Warning message:
Not a validObject(): no slot of name "srs" for this object of class "RasterLayer" 
> library(fasterRaster)
> library(raster)
> library(sp)
> library(rgrass7)
> 
> data(madForest2000)
> data(madRivers)
> data(madElev)
> 
> # calculate and plot distance to rivers
> distToRiver <- fasterVectToRastDistance(madForest2000, madRivers, grassDir=grassDir)
Error in read.dcf(con) : Line starting '���棺<PROJ_INFO> fi ...' is malformed!
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Package rgrass7 transitioning to package rgrass for GRASS 7+. 
2: Package rgrass7 transitioning to package rgrass for GRASS 7+. 
3: Package rgrass7 transitioning to package rgrass for GRASS 7+. 
4: Package rgrass7 transitioning to package rgrass for GRASS 7+. 
5: Package rgrass7 transitioning to package rgrass for GRASS 7+. 
6: Package rgrass7 transitioning to package rgrass for GRASS 7+. 
7: Package rgrass7 transitioning to package rgrass for GRASS 7+. 
8: Package rgrass7 transitioning to package rgrass for GRASS 7+. 
9: Package rgrass7 transitioning to package rgrass for GRASS 7+. 
>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Our Question/Answer model works best when you write the Question body, with a full description of the environment, software, data, and task, then describe the problem, then ask a single question, and *then* write a descriptive title (as a statement to summarize the topic). If you put the first paragraph in the title, and no descriptive text in the body, your post is likely to be closed/down-voted as a "Wall of code" question.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that the fasterRaster package is actively maintained. It functionally is just a wrapper for rgrass7 so, the depreciating package is hard-coded and very likely to throw errors.

The good news is that you can simply look at the source code and move the function calls to rgrass using GRASS V8. The [fasterVectToRastDistance](https://github.com/adamlilith/fasterRaster/blob/master/R/fasterVectToRastDistance.r) function is very straightforward to understand and translate to the new interface.